# Why my socket.io video chat won't work on heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I'm new to WS and Heroku and all that... so i have this code

//this sets up client-side sockets i guess

```
    import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
    
    const options = {
      "force new connection": true,
      reconnectionAttempts: "Infinity", 
      timeout : 10000, 
      transports : ["websocket"]
    }
    
const socket = io('/', options)

export default socket;
```

and for the server side

```
    const path = require('path');
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const server = require('http').createServer(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);
    const {version, validate} = require('uuid');
    
    const ACTIONS = require('./src/socket/actions');
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
///more code
```

When deployed to heroku this results in this app https://lit-atoll-99067.herokuapp.com/ and the chrome console says :

> WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://lit-atoll-99067.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket'
> failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

So i ran out of ideas. but i guess this has to be about port or something... dunno really. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the full URL at the client-side but you only passed the "/" only example:-

```
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
    
const options = {
  "force new connection": true,
   reconnectionAttempts: "Infinity", 
   timeout : 10000, 
   transports : ["websocket"]
}
// here need to pass the full url
const socket = io('https://example.com/', options)

export default socket;
```

And for the server side try this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: hi! that doesn't work for me. i still get console warning and there's no ws connection established between users.

Comment: Is it working in your local env

Comment: hello again. yes it does work when i initialize my client-side sockets like `const socket = io('http://localhost:3001', options)`;

Comment: and also it works on heroku with that initialization but only on my machine so i can open other browser and there will be ws connection but due to it being localhost... it doesn't work when i want to talk to other person.